# EKS - Worker nodes from multiple VPC / Accounts

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

Has anyone managed to set up an EKS cluster having worker nodes from multiple VPCs or even Accounts?

Comment: Its not supported yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Prabhat mentioned in the comment, you can only manage communication between Nodes in EKS cluster through Public and Private Subnets underlying to the same VPC in compliance with security policies for that particular AWS account.